# How to retrieve data from a RESTful service as a post request in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am new to angular js so please bear with me.

I have a backend rest implementation something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
MessageQueueResponse getInboundQueueMessages (@RequestParam(value = "request", required = true) MessageQueueRequest request)
{
        MessageQueueResponse response = messageQueueServiceImpl.searchInBoundMessageQueue(request);
        return response;
}
```

I am using this code to call this service from the front end but I am getting  **400 Bad Request**  for that:

```
var mydata = [
    {
        "A" : "data1",
        "B" : "data2",
        "C" : "data3"
    }
];

var jsonData ;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'myurl/url',
        data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function(data){
        this.data.store = data;
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
```

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Client code seems OK, the @RequestParams on the backend seem fishy.

Comment: What happens if you don't stringify the data? I don't think you need to do that.

Comment: I have removed that. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't have enough reputation to add comment so adding as answer. sorry.**

The blog shows how you can post JSON data to Spring MVC backend. [Blog Link](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/angularjs-http-service-ajax-post-json-data-code-example). 
You can try removing JSON.stringify and directly sending object.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` has a `post` method that make it very convenient to send data to a server.

```
$http.post('myurl/url', mydata)
    .success(function(data){
        this.data.store = data;
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
```

You can read more about it at [AngularJS: API: $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Answer (score 0):

There were some mistakes :

- The json object above is of array type. Which shouldn't be the case.

Also, data need not be strngyfy-ed. It will be automatically converted.